# Pendulum (highschool)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, newtonian-gravity

I have a question concerning pendulum.
On our physics lessons we built simple pendulum consisting of weight and a thread ($\ell=0.31$ m).
We tried to calculate $g$ from the well known formula

$$T_m = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}$$

which leads to

$$g = \frac{4\pi^2 \ell}{T_m^2}$$

Of course, this formula comes from conclusion that $\sin(\alpha)-\tan(\alpha)$ is neglectable for "small" $\alpha$.

Hence our target was to find formula, which works for larger $\alpha$ as well.
According to this [two](http://bacterio.uc3m.es/docencia/laboratorio/guiones_ing/mecanica/Pendulo_guide.pdf) [sources](http://ufmi.ft.utb.cz/texty/fyzika_2/F2_lab_03.pdf), this should do the trick:

$$T_m = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2}))$$

from which I came to this conclusion:

$$g=\frac{\ell\pi^2(\cos(\alpha)-9)^2}{16T_m^2}$$

Here is my problem: After using this formula and our measured data, I got $\overline g = 8.9085$, which is obviously not very accurate (for ~48°N).
Any ideas where I've made a mistake?

Comment: What value of $g$ do you get using the simple formula? In general the more complex formula gives slightly higher value of $g$.

Comment: I'm not convinced all your formulas are correct, kecer. Maybe check your algebra?

Comment: What webpage gave you that formula?

Comment: [pdf](http://ufmi.ft.utb.cz/texty/fyzika_2/F2_lab_03.pdf), but it's not in English.

I tried putting it all into [wolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T%3D2*pi*sqrt%28L%2Fg%29*%281%2B1%2F4*sin^2%28alpha%2F2%29%29%3B%20solve%20for%20g) and got the very same formula.
@Danu: according to you, is the error in the last formula or somewhere before?

Comment: I've found the same formula for larger angles in this pdf from Madrid university: [pdf, page 2, last line](http://bacterio.uc3m.es/docencia/laboratorio/guiones_ing/mecanica/Pendulo_guide.pdf)

Comment: In case you are not aware, that still is an approximation to the exact period! For the full formula, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Legendre_polynomial_solution_for_the_elliptic_integral

Comment: I have came to the same conclusion as John Rennie stated in his answer (you messed up a minus sign). And I expect that this would yield better results. However if not you might also have to deal with damping but I do not think that this would be needed.

Comment: @fibonatic: If you read John's last sentence carefully, you'll notice he has just proved me right. The minus sign doesn't really matter, since (a-b)^2==(b-a)^2

Comment: @kecer: I would measure $g$ using a range of different values for $\alpha$, i.e. use different initial displacements. You should see the calculated value of $g$ increase with angle, with the zero angle limit matching the simple formula.

Comment: @JohnRennie: I have $\alpha_{0-9}$ ranging from 11.54° to 83.54°. Here is a nested array with related values [T,$\alpha$]

[[1.15, 11.54], [1.16, 26.57], [1.18, 39.49], [1.18, 44.11], [1.2, 52.15], [1.22, 58.29], [1.23, 63.96], [1.25, 66.53], [1.28, 73.78], [1.3, 83.54]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE

I finally got it right. My thanks goes to @NeuroFuzzy, who pointed me in the right direction.
According to wiki's **Legendre polynomial solution for the elliptic integral**, "*an exact solution to the period of a pendulum is:*"

$$T=2\pi\sqrt\frac{\ell}{g}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2}\right)^2sin^{2n}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right]$$

which after solving for g gives

$$g=\ell\left(2\pi \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left[\left(\frac{(2n)!}{(2^nn!)^2}\right)^2sin^{2n}\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)\right]T^{-1} \right)^2$$

Although it is probably not the most beautiful wonder of the world, it seems to work for me. I finally get acceptable results ($\overline g = 9.402$). The difference between real and this g can easily be explained, therefore I mark this post as the real answer. In case somebody is interested in this, [here is python2 code](http://pastebin.com/n9MxpDpM) for finding g from measured data.

## Original answer

After reading your answers, suggestions and after going through simplification of the formula once again (with the very same result), I have to conclude that, assuming

$$T_m = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2}))$$

is correct (taken from two independent sources), following formula is correct as well

$$g=\frac{\ell\pi^2(\cos(\alpha)-9)^2}{16T_m^2}$$

*This suggests my experiment alone was not very accurate, thus resulting in the error seen in my original question.*

## Additional info

I have tried to come up with the formula for $T_m$ but with no luck. I got
$$T=2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell\cos(\alpha)}{g}}$$
from which one can easily get
$$g=\frac{4\ell\pi^2\cos(\alpha)}{T^2}$$
Although it looks little bit similar, it's not quite there. It also returns unacceptable results ($\overline g = 4.94$)

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment to Mathbreaker's answer, but it's hard to do formulae in comments.

If you simply solve:

$$ T_m = 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}(1+\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(\tfrac{\alpha}{2})) $$

for $g$ you get:

$$ g = \frac{4 \pi^2 l (4 + \sin^2(\tfrac{\alpha}{2}))^2}{16 \tau^2} \tag{1} $$

We use the identity:

$$ \sin^2(\tfrac{\alpha}{2}) = \tfrac{1}{2} - \tfrac{1}{2}\cos\alpha $$

Substituting this in (1) gives:

$$\begin{align}
 g &= \frac{4 \pi^2 l (4 + \tfrac{1}{2} - \tfrac{1}{2}\cos\alpha)^2}{16 \tau^2} \\
   &= \frac{\pi^2 l (9 - \cos\alpha)^2}{16 \tau^2}
\end{align}$$

which is kecer's formula (give or take a factor of -1 that gets squared anyway).

Answer (score 0):

$$g= \frac{L *4\pi^2 * ((5- \cos^2 (\alpha/2))^2}{16T^2}$$ 
This is what i got when i simplified for $g$.

I assume you made some mistake in simplification, or it just might be me, Iapologize if it is. You could try plugging your values into this and hope for an answer...

when i simplify the latter part as well i get 
$$\frac{L * 4\pi^2 *(25+\cos^4(\alpha/2) - 10\cos^2(\alpha/2))}{16T^2}$$

Either there is a mistake in the formula you have obtained online, or in simplification. 
Also, there is a possibility that your measure data wouldve been inaccurate due to parallax error or otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Danu for correcting original answer. I get more accurate results with it (g~=9.205), which might just be the correct answer for me. I'll try to simplify the formula once again, maybe I'll get it right this time.

Comment: Haha all the best :D
I'm thinking you used the formula sin(a+b) = sinacosb - cosasinb wrongly so you missed the 2, and not entirely sure where you got that 9 from. Kudos!

Comment: @Mathbreaker: see my answer for the derivation of kecer's formula for $g$.